# iOS: Bottom thubnail bar in a image view for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, photo

Is there any class in iOS like Android 's gallery class can handle thumbnails in a bar?

a little like iPad's camera roll, there is a **thumbnail bar** in the bottom of the photo grid view

thank you!
If there is none,
 I know maybe can use **slide bar** or **scroll view** in a UIview to implement what I want.
Can anybody can tell more about how to use scrollview or slider to implement this?
Further more, I haven't think clear is: how do the thumbnails and the big image view delegate to each other?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use UISegmentControl in Viewcontroller's Titleview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a great example of what you are looking for [thumbnailpickerview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/thumbnailpickerview)

or you can use iCarousel library to create scrolling thumbnails as well. here is the link [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)